# TKinter Trouble getting Entry Value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with TKinter in Python 2.7, I cannot seem to get the value out of this entry object and I cannot figure out why.

```
def compute():
    a = float(side_one_entry.get())

side_one_entry = Entry(justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)

go_button = Button(root, text="GO", command=compute).grid(row=10, columnspan=4)
```

I am crashing at the a = ... line. I have double checked that all rows columns line up correctly

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The problem is when you ad .grid(..) to your Entrydeclaration, it does not return to side_one_entry the widget object but the return value of grid() - which is None.
So side_one_entry = None
Put the grid instruction on a new line
side_one_entry.grid(  ... )

Comment: @jimscafe, you are right. thanks

Comment: Could you be so kind as to tell us what tutorial or documentation is suggesting you do `Entry(...).grid(...)`. There must be hundreds of similar questions on this site. Maybe we can contact the authors of the documentation/tutorial to suggest a better way of programming.

Comment: Mr. Oakley, I do wish experienced stack members would give beginners a little slack. I know this has been answered many times before, but beginners do not always know how to find those answers, how to ask the question in the best way. They soon learn and become valuable members of this community. Downgrading an answer within minutes of being asked can be demoralizing. Just a suggestion, I know you provide valuable answers on more complex questions.